# Python: How to create a function to get a data from url and send it to other location asynchronously?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I tried to understand the asynchronous programming.

So I made a small async function.

The function I made is that it reads contents from multiple websites and send them to certain urls asynchronously.

I wrote a async function something like this

```
import requests
import asyncio

getter_sender_list = [
    ('https://google.com', 'http://localhost:5000/receiver_1'),
    ('https://yahoo.com', 'http://localhost:5000/receiver_2'),
    ('https://stackoverflow.com', 'http://localhost:5000/receiver_3'),
]

def main():
    async def transfer_data(getter, sender):
        r = await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get(getter))
        data = r.content
        res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.post(sender, data=data))
        print('Single Transfer Complete')

    async def transfer_all():
        coroutines = [transfer_data(getter, sender) for getter, sender in getter_sender_list]
        await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
        print('TRANSFER COMPLETE')

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(transfer_all())
```

Is the approach I take correct?

or do i need to consider something different?

Answer (score 0):

I think the coroutines is needed to chanege like this

```
coroutines = [asyncio.ensure_future(transfer_data(getter, sender)) for getter, sender in getter_sender_list]
```

and you can check the code run in asyncronous with time

```
from time import time

begin = time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()          
loop.run_until_complete(transfer_all())          
loop.close()                             
end = time()
print('running time: {0:.3f}sec'.format(end - begin))
```

Comment: Does ensure_future make coroutines not to wait? Then the time spent is not different btw yourss and mine. Am i right?

Comment: yeah, I have been recomeded using ensure_futrue before, but i didn't understand exact difference with not using that methods. sorry about it
I also need expert of async